# UICollectionViewCell image shadow works only after scrolling

Tags: ios, iphone, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Using custom `UICollectionViewCell` with `imageView` and it applied with shadows.

This shadows applied to the cells only after scrolling not working at initially visible cells.

Could any assist to resolve this?

I also tried for `cell.setNeedsDisplay` and adding `collectionview.ReloadData` in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: can you provide the code of shadow? @Gobi M

Comment: UIBezierPath shadowPath = UIBezierPath.FromRect(imageView.Bounds);
   imageView.Layer.ShadowColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;
   imageView.Layer.ShadowOffset = new CoreGraphics.CGSize(0f, 0f);
   imageView.Layer.ShadowOpacity= 0.6f;
   imageView.Layer.ShadowRadius = 7.0f;
   imageView.Layer.ShadowPath = shadowPath.CGPath;
   imageView.Layer.BorderWidth = 2.0f;